# How do I default a parameter to Guid.Empty in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

for Index action i need to pass Guid but it should be null as i'm checking it for edit or delete action.

I have used like this but getting compile error : Guid Cannot be null must be compile time constant.
or runtime error :

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'uid' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String, System.Guid)' in 'Mapping.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

```
public ActionResult Index(string userAction, Guid uid = new Guid() )
        {
----
----
}
```

Comment: Despite the answers you will get about how to manage nullable type optional parameter, are you sure is it the right thing to do, to choose the action (edit or delete) based on a parameter on Index Action of your controller? It sounds to me you should have dedicated Actions

Comment: how can i do something like if (uid>0) then do edit or delete when we have uid as Guid???
Currently i'm checking like  if (objModel.Id != null) that is not working

Comment: I answered in a propr answer... but the point is, as far as I understand, you're following the wrong approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) `Guid` for your parameter:

```
public ActionResult Index(string userAction, Guid? uid = null)
```

Based on your comments, assuming `objModel.Id` is a `Guid`, you can use:

```
objModel.Id != default(Guid)
```

However, knowing more about your situation now, I would look to `themarcuz`'s answer for a better overall solution.

Comment: it is taking default value like 0000-0000-0000-0000 not null :(

Comment: how can i do something like if (uid>0) then do edit or delete when we have uid as Guid???
Currently i'm checking like  if (objModel.Id != null) that is not working

Answer (score 1):

You should evaluate the condition in the caller's View, and calls two different action, one for editing and one for deleting.
Something like that (in the caller's View):

```
@if (existGuid)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {myGuid = guid})
}
else
{
     @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete")
}
```

And then in your controller, you'll have different Action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid myGuid)
{
    // do something here
}
public ActionResult Delete()
{
    // do something here
}
```

Even if I don't understand how can you delete something without passing any parameters...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in the route that parameter as optional.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{guid}", // URL with parameters
                new {controller = "DefaultController", action = "Index", guid = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

After that you don't have to have guid as a parameter in the Index action, or you can have both actions like

`Index()` and `Index(Guid guid)`

Comment: how can i do something like if (uid>0) then do edit or delete when we have uid as Guid???
Currently i'm checking like  if (objModel.Id != null) that is not working

Comment: Although it's not clear, but I think you're trying to handle the default action and a post action where you expect a guid. That's exactly what I was proposing you to do. In your default action you do not expect a guid, and when you post you expect a guid in the same action. Also, you can try parse the uid as a guid and then proceed as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom model binder that was pass a `Guid.Empty` value instead `null` for a `Guid?` action method parameter.