# ASP.NET Core: Default value for Guid parameter in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it possible to provide a default value to a Guid parameter in an ASP.Net core (.net 7) web api?

Like this:

```
[HttpGet()]
public async Task<ActionResult<Foo>> PostSomething(Guid tenantId = "21c10283-6db0-489b-94d0-f0b3969fc799") // <<-- invalid of course
```

So far I'm using an optional parameter and assigning the default value in the method, but I'd like to expose it in the signature if possible.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Foo>> PostSomething(Guid? tenantId) 
{
   tenantId ??= Guid.Parse("21c10283-6db0-489b-94d0-f0b3969fc799");
```

Note: Other answers show how to set an empty default value, but thats not what I need here.

// Edit: If this is not possible at all, thats also an answer. But please read the question carefully before posting anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I default a parameter to Guid.Empty in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229006/how-do-i-default-a-parameter-to-guid-empty-in-mvc)

Comment: @MohammedAlwedaei no, since I dont want to set an empty default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you cannot expose the default value in the signature, you can set it using the [`DefaultValueAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute), which is picked up by Swashbuckle and presumably other tooling.

Here's an example:

```cs
private const string defaultTenantId = "21c10283-6db0-489b-94d0-f0b3969fc799";

[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<Foo>> PostSomething(
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Guid), defaultTenantId)] Guid? tenantId) 
{
   tenantId ??= Guid.Parse(defaultTenantId);

   // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// define your default or take it from somewhere
static Guid defaultGuid = Guid.Parse("21c10283-6db0-489b-94d0-f0b3969fc799");

// use this function to get your guid
public static Guid GetGuidOrDefault(Guid? guid) => guid ?? defaultGuid;

public async Task<ActionResult<Foo>> PostSomething(Guid? tenantId) 
{
    // but it is extremely wrong to change the values of function parameters
    tenantId = GetGuidOrDefault(tenantId);
```

Comment: so how is this better than what I'm currently doing? :) Its still not part of the method signature

Comment: What should be a part of the method signature?

Comment: the default value Guid("21c10283-6db0-489b-94d0-f0b3969fc799"), so that - for instance - swagger will generate the API definition including the default

Comment: You mean something like `public async Task<ActionResult<Foo>> PostSomething(Guid? tenantId, Guid defauilGuidIs_21c10283_6db0_489b_94d0_f0b3969fc799)`?

Comment: no, pretty much like in the example I posted in my question. You can provide defaults for string, int, etc. as well in the same manner

Comment: The small difference is that my example 'll became a part of swagger doc.

Answer (score -1):

how about with `tenantId ??= default(Guid);`?
you can also use for other datatypes like `string`, etc.

Comment: see above: I dont want to assign the default value of Guid (with is Guid.Empty)